# Requesting clarification/feedback for the big(o) runtime on this function

Tags: python, runtime, big-o

So we were asked to determine the big o runtime for this python function:

```
def contain_letters_in_common(string1, string2):

    duplicates = []
    for letter in string1:
        if letter in string2:
            if letter not in duplicates:
                duplicates.append(letter)

    return len(duplicates) > 0
```

And we were told that the runtime is O(n^2).  I'd like to get some feedback on if this is true as a few of us thought that it should be O(m*n) with m and n being the length of the 2 strings.

can someone please explain which is the correct runtime (

Comment: The correct way to do this is return len(set(string1).intersection(string2)) - at least you should create dupliates as set() not at list. O(n) describes the worst case: the worst case here is that string1 and string2 have no letters in common at all. in that case you walk all of string1 times all of string2 times wich is 0(m*n) if you desire the strings to be of different lengths

Comment: You are correct its O(m*n)

Comment: @Patrick-Artner, thank you very much for the explanation of how you arrived at that runtime!  (and also for the tip on how to better implement the function)

Comment: @Kraigolas Thank you for the confirmation Kraidolas! we thought that it should be the case but it's nice to get confirmation from someone with more experience.